# Operand data type numeric is invalid for '~' operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, bigint

~ operator is not working for BIGINT datatype,

```
UPDATE Table
SET attrEx= attrEx & (~576460752303423488 )
where attrEx != 0
```

attrEx Type : `BIGINT`

Error:

> Operand data type numeric is invalid for '~' operator.

Comment: Can you please add more detail to your question? Currently, it's not clear what are you trying to achieve from the above

Comment: the value is too huge to be treated as integer and `~` does not work on numeric. Refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @JayasuryaSatheesh I just need the negation(~) of big int

Comment: @Squirrel It's actually not too big for a `bigint`, just needs a cast https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8169128d2a141b4c0a89d277a8a37f57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to `bigint`

```sql
UPDATE Table
SET attrEx= attrEx & (~CAST(576460752303423488 AS bigint) )
where attrEx != 0
```

This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)

> Functions return `bigint` only if the parameter expression is a `bigint` data type. SQL Server does not automatically promote other integer data types (`tinyint`, `smallint`, and `int`) to `bigint`.
> *...snip...*
> Integer constants greater than 2,147,483,647 are converted to the `decimal` data type, not the `bigint` data type.